# Angular 4.3 HttpClient Chunked Uploads

Tags: angular, file-upload, chunks, chunked-encoding, angular4-httpclient

I have to deal with huge file uploads (over 4GB). Currently I am using the new HttpClient.
Is it possible to set a option for chunked uploads in the new HttpClient Module in Angular 4.3? 
I found a solution for Angularjs with the ng-file-upload module. Unfortunately it is not available for angular 4.
Thank you for help in advance.